# Fail to start Synaptic on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: synaptic

Just did fresh install Ubuntu 14.04, which comes with unity, and after that I installed ubuntu gnome desktop. At the beginning synaptic has no problem, then after I installed another package (gimp,if I remember correctly), I got this message when try to run synaptic

```
Error in `synaptic': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000026f2cb0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Anyone of you guys got the same error? Any solution appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Just to confirm that you have rebooted your computer?  How about apt-get, apt-cache, and aptitude: do they work?  Is there anything interesting in your logfiles? syslog, dmesg, etc?

Comment: Yes I have. apt-get, apt-cache work OK. I'm not sure which log to see, where to find it? Sorry I'm just ordinary ubuntu user, not an expert.

Comment: log files are in /var/log  You probably want to look in syslog.

Comment: I see nothing wrong. but the same problem happened in 13.10 as well, as in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206178, and no solution until now. Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have some bad hardware that is intermittently failing.

Try the StressLinux distro:
http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/

Or you try the `stress` package directly.

Or it could be you have some bad memory?  Ubuntu ships with a memory test that is access through the grub menu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest

It could a loose connection in a chip or something, and when your computer warms up the the circuitry changes.

Also, how does `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` work for you?  What is the command that you ran aptitude with?

Comment: I did memtest86+, and everything seems ok, no memory fault found. And apt-get and apt-get upgrade work without any problem.

Comment: I guess the problem might be associated with glib?, as the nautilus also got error as follow

*** Error in `nautilus': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000002601ff0 ***